# How to get the full stack trace for WordPress "table doesn't exist" error in debug.log?

Tags: database, errors, debug

I'm getting a WordPress "table doesn't exist" error in my debug.log, but unlike most errors it doesn't give a full stack trace to help me isolate the code. Anyone know how to tell WordPress to dump a full stack trace for this error? Thanks!

```
[03-Apr-2021 08:19:39 UTC] WordPress database error Table '**********.wp_47_wslusersprofiles' doesn't exist for query SELECT id, object_sha FROM `wp_47_wslusersprofiles` where user_id = 33 and provider = 'Google' and identifier = '115473556036777077042' made by require('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wsl_process_login, wsl_process_login_end, wsl_process_login_update_wsl_user_data, wsl_store_hybridauth_user_profile
```

---

*More context:* I know the `wslusersprofiles` table isn't a standard WordPress table. What puzzles me is why I'm not getting a normal stack trace in my `debug.log` file like I would for a PHP Error, Warning, or Notice. It's as if the WordPress database class is trapping this error and only issuing an `error_log()` notification, without throwing a PHP error. Is there a way to force it to throw an exception? Or at least dump more details?

Comment: those tables aren't WordPrress tables, they're coming from a custom plugin. Look for a plugin or theme that uses `wsl` and does things with user profiles that adds the `wslusersprofiles` table, you will need to contact their support rroute

Comment: Thanks, but I know the `wslusersprofiles` table isn't a standard WordPress table. My question is how to get a stack track so I can identify and debug the code that is causing this error. I'll edit my question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not seeing a stack trace because this information is being logged via the [`error_log()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) within the [`wpdb::print_error()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/print_error/). `error_log()` simply sends a message to the logs.

The behaviour you're expecting with a full stack trace would require [`trigger_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) to be used.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Yes indeed... looking at the WP source code, it looks like there's no way to force it to dump a stack trace (no magic `define` variable, etc.). But I should be able to get it with an `XDEBUG` breakpoint. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.